# When is a lattice dense in a torus?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, lie-groups, vector-lattices

Let $\pi: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$.  What (necessary and sufficient) criteria on $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ guarantee $\pi(A\mathbb{Z}^n)$ is dense?

Comment: Can you answer the $n=1$ case?

Comment: A irrational...

Comment: Why not $A$ a diagonal matrix with irrational entries? Doesn't the $n = 1$-case "apply", when regarding $\mathbb{R}^n / \mathbb{Z}^n \cong \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z} \times \dots \times \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @M.U.  right, I was hoping for necessary and sufficient criteria though. I should probably specify

Answer (score 1):

One criterion comes from Kronecker's theorem:  $\pi(A\mathbb{Z}^n)$ is dense if and only if $A^t(\mathbb{Z}^m\backslash \{0\})$ does not contain an integer vector. I.e. the rows of $A$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ from every rational vector.